# Why is the missed approach point sometimes beyond the threshold or runway like in the example below?

Tags: iaps, go-around, missed-approach

Why is the missed approach point beyond the threshold or sometimes beyond the runway like in the picture below? Is it just to simplify the ATC job or prevent routes from crossing or is it procedural?

[image: LTBU VOR A]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The missed approach point (MAP) needs to be **identified** somehow by the pilot flying this approach.

The example you show is a VOR approach that requires neither RNAV/RNP capability nor DME. That is also why you see a duration (3 Min or 2 Min) for the outbound leg instead of a fix (there is an optional RNAV fix [FS044] that may be used if you are RNAV capable, but it is not required).

The only point that can be identified here is the VOR itself. Therefore, the procedure is constructed with the VOR as the MAP, even if that happens to be after the runway. Note that you can execute a missed approach earlier than the MAP (that is the latest point, where you have to execute it).

If you look at the similar **VOR Z Rwy 04** approach with straight-in minima, you see **DME required** at the top, which allows defining a MAP before reaching the runway via DME:

[image]

Comment: What advantage is there to flying the VOR Z (with DME) instead of VOR A (with stopwatch)? Or more to the point maybe, what advantage is there to publishing it? Are the minimums lower for the VOR Z? If so that might be something to include in the answer/screengrab.

Comment: @randomhead Yes, the VOR Z has lower straight-in minima (900'), the VOR A is circle-to-land only. Not sure how that's relevant for the answer though...

Comment: Not strictly relevant but I think it would add to overall understanding.

Comment: @randomhead Modern avionics automatically show the distance to the next fix (via GPS substituted for DME), which is a lot easier for the pilot than a operating a stopwatch and doing math, especially when hand-flying the plane.